# SQLite Android get distinct values

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I have a SQLite Database for my levels for a game, with data from `Name, Campaign, Number, Score`. While building my LevelList (ListView with custom Views), I want to choose a Campaign from a list, where you can see the highscore next to it, which is obtained by adding all the scores from this campaign's levels in the database.

Every Level in the database has a campaign field of the one it's part of. But to make a campaign list, I only want to get distinct (unique) campaigns. Is there a good way to get these from the Database?
 What's the best way to get these, and also get the total scores?

part of the database and how i'm going to make my levelpicker listview:
[image]

Comment: I think it needs some clarification. 1) post some sketch/explanation about your campain list idea, and 2) how your tables are built (what columns).

Comment: `select campain,sum(score) from gdata group by campain` ... if i got it right. if you want to add player add player to select and `group by`

Comment: Doesn't `select campaign..` also return the duplicates from campaign? And also, doesn't this give me the score sum of ALL levels?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select * from gdata

 campain        num     name       file       score     player    
 -------------  ------  ---------  ---------  --------  --------- 
 Campain One    1       Level One  test1.xml  1221      john      
 Campain One    1       Level Two  test1.xml  122       john      
 Campain One    1       Level Two  test1.xml  122       dereck    
 Campain One    1       Level Two  test1.xml  122       jon       
 Campain Two    1       Level Two  test1.xml  122       jon       
 Campain Two    1       Level Two  test1.xml  122       jon       
 Campain Two    1       Level Two  test2.xml  122       jon       
 Campain Three  1       Level Two  test2.xml  1122      jon       
 Campain Three  1       Level Two  test2.xml  1122      jon       
 Campain Three  1       Level Two  test2.xml  1122      derekk
```

---

```
select 'All' as campain ,'All'as player,sum(score) score from gdata
union
select campain,player,sum(score) as score from gdata group by campain,player

 campain        player     score    
 -------------  ---------  -------- 
 All            All        5319     
 Campain One    dereck     122      
 Campain One    john       1343     
 Campain One    jon        122      
 Campain Three  derekk     1122     
 Campain Three  jon        2244     
 Campain Two    jon        366
```

---

```
select campain,sum(score) as score from gdata group by campain

 campain        score    
 -------------  -------- 
 Campain One    1587     
 Campain Three  3366     
 Campain Two    366
```

---

```
select campain,player,max(score) from (
select campain,player,sum(score) as score from gdata 
group by campain,player order by score desc
) as b
group by campain  

 campain        player     score
 -------------  ---------  ------------- 
 Campain One    john       1343          
 Campain Three  jon        2244          
 Campain Two    jon        366
```

Comment: Wow great, thanks! I tried it out and it gave good results. I thought `group by` would like sort them. The 3rd example, together with `player` is exactly what I needed, but the other ones are also great, for example highscore list. I'm going to try to implement it now.

Comment: glad to help. set it as an answer then please.